# get page templates

Tags: templates

I have this issue where I need to get all page templates. I know there are ways to get them based on their name. I know that I can include a page template but I am trying to include them in the loop on the index page. I just installed the 2012 theme, modified the header to include my scripts. I used a function that Milo offered from this site to load all posts and pages into the homepage which is working. Now I need to include all templates even those that I don't know their name.

looking in the codex, I found a function called [get_page_templates()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_templates) that doesn't appear to be valid anymore. it gave this snippet

```
 <?php 
    $templates = get_page_templates();
    foreach ( $templates as $template_name => $template_filename ) {
    echo "$template_name ($template_filename)<br />";
    }
 ?>
```

This code snippet should have done the trick but it gave me an invalid function error.
I messed around with get_page_template() but all it would return for me is page.php

Looking in the database in the _wp_post_meta, I see the field _wp_page_template and I can see that it holds all the template names that I need to include. I am just not sure how to get those names out of that field.

I tried this

```
$template = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_wp_page_template',true);
```

but when I checked the value of $template, I found nothing.

can you help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking for `get_page_templates()` in the [core](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/theme.php#L83), I found a workaround that doesn't break the theme like:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_page_templates()

I'm using this just after `<body>` and works ok:

```
$templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();

foreach ( $templates as $template_name => $template_filename ) 
{
    echo "$template_name ($template_filename)<br />";
}
```

Comment: I think this will only return the "page" templates and not the entire list of files.

Comment: @Wyck, yes, that's what I understood of the Q...

Comment: It used to return all the files at some point , I think it was confusing.

Comment: this is an interesting solution. What if you want to get the template information though? Like the_title? Your snippet just returns template names right? I forgot to take into account in my original post that I do also need other information like the_title outside of the template query. Some very helpful information in this thread. I like it

Comment: @Jamie, but `the_title` is a property of a post, not of a template file by itself, no? Check [the content](http://i.imgur.com/XfJcNdz.png) of `$firephp->log(wp_get_theme());`

Answer (score 3):

That example in the codex is not valid anymore, this code was changed somewhere between 3.3--3.5.

An alternative way to is to use the following.

```
$stylesheet = get_stylesheet();
$theme = wp_get_theme( $stylesheet );
// this will only return .php files extend as needed
$allowed_files = $theme->get_files( 'php', 1 );

var_dump($allowed_files); // see what is there
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This was my solution. Do you have a better one? after the endwhile, I did this ( all my templates are stored in the inc folder)

```
 <?php $args = array( 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template');
        $templates = get_pages($args);
        foreach ( $templates as $template){
            $templateName = $template->meta_value;
            if( $templateName != 'default' && $templateName !='') include('inc/'. $templateName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a valid function, you just can't use it on the front end because `theme.php` file isn't loaded on the front end, you'd have to include it-

```
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/theme.php';
$templates = get_page_templates();
```

It doesn't give you what you actually need though, brasofilo and Wyck's answers are likely the ones you want.

Comment: But why does `wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates()` work by itself? I get that the OP wants all `page templates`, not theme templates...

Comment: @brasofilo it's a different file, `wp-admin/includes/theme.php` vs `wp-includes/theme.php`