# View WordPress page template usage (or unused)

Tags: templates, themes

When I create a new page within WordPress, I have the option of specifying which template to use from my theme (from a dropdown list on the right-hand side of the interface).

I need to find which of the available templates are unused, so that I can delete them.

How is this done please?

WP version is 4.2.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is compare the values of the meta field `_wp_page_template`, which contains the page template selected for a single page with the available page templates.

For this you need to construct an array of used templates, because you want the templates used by all the pages, similar as shown here:

- [Return all custom meta data for one custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45272/22534)

Use `array_unique` to get unique values.

Then you need to get the available page templates, as shown here:

- [get page templates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/83180/22534)

Last but not least, you can use `array_diff` to compare the arrays of used and available templates, which subsequently gives you the unused templates.

Comment: Great, thanks.  As my strengths lie in database land rather than PHP, I used the following SQL code to provide a similar output, which can be tweaked later with counts, etc `SELECT p.post_title as PostTitle, m.meta_value as Template
FROM \`wp_postmeta\` as m join 
\`wp_posts\` as p ON p.ID = m.post_id
where 
((p.post_type = 'page') OR 
(p.post_type = 'post')) AND
(m.meta_key = '_wp_page_template');`.  Your input was invaluable to pointing out where the correct database fields were.

Comment: My pleasure! Sure SQL is a way too. Just as a general tip, when available and suitable use WordPress API functions, it makes WP development easier in the long run. I said my piece :) @EvilDr

Answer (score 3):

*Update:*

### Page Template Usage Info in WordPress 4.4+

In WordPress 4.4 the `array_intersect_assoc()` was removed from the `WP_Theme::get_page_templates()` method.

See ticket [#13265](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13265) and changeset [#34995](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/34995).

We can therefore add the page templates usage info, directly into the *template dropdown*, with the `theme_page_templates` filter, without using javascript or some clever object cache tricks explained [here by @MikeSchinkel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/198064/26350) or [here by @gmazzap](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/143054/26350).

Here's a demo (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', function( $page_templates, $obj, $post )
{
    // Restrict to the post.php loading
    if( ! did_action( 'load-post.php' ) )
        return $page_templates;

    foreach( (array) $page_templates as $key => $template )
    {
        $posts = get_posts( 
            [
                'post_type'      => 'any',
                'post_status'    => 'any', 
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'fields'         => 'ids',
                'meta_query'     => [
                    [
                        'key'       => '_wp_page_template',
                        'value'     => $key,
                        'compare'   => '=',
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );

        $count = count( $posts );

        // Add the count to the template name in the dropdown. Use 10+ for >= 10
        $page_templates[$key] = sprintf( 
            '%s (%s)', 
            $template, 
             $count >= 10 ? '10+' : $count
        );          
    }
    return $page_templates;
}, 10, 3 );
```

**Example:**

Here we can see how it could look like, with the usage count info added to the template names :

[image: template usage info]

Hope you can adjust this to your needs!

Comment: Neat idea, nearly impossible though to overcome the restriction by the core code - with PHP. The `page_template_dropdown()` function also doesn't give the possibility.

Comment: Sometimes it's just one line of code in the core that makes  the difference ;-) Javascript could be one way to adjust the template dropdown, or one could try `preg_replace()` on the output from  `page_attributes_meta_box()` to swap the dropdown, or just try to extend the `WP_Theme` class. Or some other way ;-) @ialocin

Comment: Sure sometimes it is just one line and sometimes it is almost all of it :) And sure, where there is a will there's a way.

Comment: hehe and sometimes it's just WordPress ;-)

Comment: Looks like WordPress 4.4 was the lucky version ;-) @ialocin